# WPF TreeView template with different classes

Tags: c#, wpf

How to write XAML for WPF TreeView so when I bind ViewModel with following structure?

```
public class A
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    public List<B> ItemsB { get; set; }
    public List<C> ItemsC { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    public List<D> ItemsD { get; set; }
}
public class D
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

TreeView should look something like this:

```
-Item1 (class A)
    - Id: 1, Name: Item 1b (class B)
    - Id: 2, Name: Item 2b (class B)
    - Id: 1, Name: Item 3c (class C)
          - Id: 1, Name: Item 4d (class D)
-Item2 (class A)
    - Id: 2, Name: Item 1c (class C)
    - Id: 3, Name: Item 2b (class B)
    - Id: 3, Name: Item 3c (class C)
...
```

I've tried with `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and `DataTemplate` but all I can get is list of `A` items with only `ItemsB` listed as child nodes but never `ItemsC`. Its a bit complicated since we are mixing different objects (`B`s and `C`s) in same hierarchical level. All solutions I tried are something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564985/using-hierarchicaldatatemplate-with-different-nested-types) but I only get 1st level (`A`), never the child items.

How should XAML be set for this case?

Comment: It would be straightforward without class B, and A only having ItemsC. The ItemsD member in C could just be null or empty.

Comment: Then all boils down to a single class X with an Id, a Name and a `List<X> Items` property.

Comment: Can't modify structure, it has to be like that. Its location which has different types of devices, A has devices of type B and C (B and C have same base class if it helps).

Comment: You can probably wrap A into a class with a property like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673232/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the tree structure (class structure):

```
<TreeView.Resources>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type A}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsB}">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
      <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsC}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type B}">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type C}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsD}">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type D}">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

The `Style` to adjust the appearance. It's the default `TreeViewItem` style taken from [Microsoft Docs: TreeView Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/treeview-styles-and-templates#treeview-controltemplate-example) with a modified "Expander" positioning and removed border of the nested `TreeView` to maintain the default look. You can apply the `Style` (and its resources) locally by setting the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` property or by putting the `Style` into a `ResourceDictionary` within the scope of the target `TreeView`(e.g., *App.xaml*):

```
<!-- Remove the border of the nested TreeView -->
<Style TargetType="TreeView">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
</Style>

<Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

<Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle"
       TargetType="ToggleButton">
  <Setter Property="Focusable"
          Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid Width="15"
              Height="13"
              Background="Transparent">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="Collapsed">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="Expanded">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Path x:Name="Collapsed"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="1,1,1,1"
                Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z">
            <Path.Fill>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
            </Path.Fill>
          </Path>
          <Path x:Name="Expanded"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="1,1,1,1"
                Data="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"
                Visibility="Hidden">
            <Path.Fill>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
            </Path.Fill>
          </Path>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border>
          <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0"
                     StrokeThickness="5"
                     Stroke="Black"
                     StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                     Opacity="0" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="1,0,0,0" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
          Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                              Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
            (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
              <VisualState x:Name="SelectedInactive">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
            (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

          <!-- Adjust the positioning of the item expander -->
          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="0,2,0,0"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

          <Border x:Name="Bd"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>
          <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                   Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                         Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Width"
                         Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="75" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                         Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Height"
                         Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="19" />
          </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

### Recommended

You should definitely change the class structure and introduce a common base type:

```
interface IDevice
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  List<IDevice> Items { get; set; }
}

class A : IDevice
{
  public A()
  {
    this.Items = new List<IDevice> { new B(), new C() };
  }
}

class B : IDevice
{}
```

You can now add every type that implements `IDevice` to the child collection, even mixed. Simply add a `HierachricalDataTemplate` for each implementation of `IDevice`:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type A}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type B}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type C}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type D}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: Combined it with solution from above - works but it doesn't look great. Will try to improve.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't look good? Styling? You have to pretty it up. It was just an example on how to build a proper tree structure, allowing different data types.

Comment: Also note that "*solution from above*" makes no sense. Users of this site can control the order in which answers are listed.

Comment: I've messed up replies, I used BionicCode answer and one @Clemens wrote was good idea/inspiration what to do next. Yes, styling is and issue but I think it can be improved.

Comment: I have added the modified default `Style` of the `TreeViewItem` to adjust the positioning of the item expander. A `Style` that targets `TreeView` removes the border of the nested `TreeView`. Now the complete `TreeView` will look like expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the ItemsB and ItemsC collections of class A into a CompositeCollection.

Since `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource` is not a collection, but a `BindingBase` it seems not possible to do this directly in XAML. You may however write a Binding Converter:

```
public class ClassAItemsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var a = (A)value;

        return new CompositeCollection
        {
            new CollectionContainer() { Collection = a.ItemsB },
            new CollectionContainer() { Collection = a.ItemsC }
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The templates would look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ClassAItemsConverter x:Key="AItemsConverter"/>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:A}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AItemsConverter}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:C}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsD}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:B}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:D}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Used this solution, it's kinda ugly (because of nested TreeView) but its ok as stopgap solution until we devise a prettier one. Or if someone has an idea how to make it looking like default treeview, please write.

Comment: You probably wanted to write this comment to the other answer, There is no nested TreeView here.

Comment: Yes, I mixed them up but anyway it was useful answer, gave me idea what to do next.